# Parse string using grep, sed or awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a string that looks like this

```
807001S:S6S11ABB23668732CC1DD1496851208.807262EE7482
```

I need output like this:

```
S:S6S11,07001,23668732,1,1496851208,807262,7482
```

I need the string with the column separated like this:

```
S:S6 + the next 3 characters;
```

In this case `S:S6S11` this works:

```
echo 807001S:S6S11ABB23668732CC1DD1496851208.807262EE7482 |
grep -P -o  'F:S6.{1,3}'
```

Output:

```
S:S6S11
```

This gets me close, getting just the numbers

```
echo 807001S:S6S11ABB23668732CC1DD1496851208.807262EE7482 | 
grep -o '[0-9]\+' | tr '\n' ','
```

Output:

```
807001,6,11,23668732,1,1496851208,807262,7482,
```

How can I get `S:S6S11` in the beginning of my output and avoid `6,11` after that?

If this can be done better with sed or awk I don't mind.

#### Edit - clarification of structure

The rest of the string is:

- LETTERS NUMBERS
- BB 23668732
- CC 1
- DD 1496851208.807262
- EE 7482

I need just the numbers but they have to correspond to the letters.

Comment: How exactly is the data you're parsing structured? Can you break it down into logical tokens? You did it for `S:S6`, but left out details about the rest of it. What are the other fields in your output? What do they specify, what are the valid values for them?

Comment: Edited to add more

Comment: What happened to the `8` at the beginning of the line in the first example?

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ echo "807001S:S6S11ABB23668732CC1DD1496851208.807262EE7482" | 
awk '{pre=gensub(".*(S:S6...).*","\\1","g");    ## extract prefix
      sub(/./,",");                             ## replace first char with comma
      gsub(/[^0-9]+/,",");                      ## replace non-numeric values with comma
      print pre $0}'                            ## print prefix and replaced line


S:S6S11,07001,6,11,23668732,1,1496851208,807262,7482
```

Answer (score 1):

... or `sed`:

```
$ echo "807001S:S6S11ABB23668732CC1DD1496851208.807262EE7482" | sed -re 's/^.([0-9]+)(S:S6...)ABB([0-9]+)CC([0-9]+)DD([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)EE([0-9]*)$/\2,\1,\3,\4,\5,\6,\7/'
S:S6S11,07001,23668732,1,1496851208,807262,7482
```

That is, if your line format is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GNU awk, you can simplify the task by defining `RS` as the desired pattern, e.g.:

*parse.awk*

```awk
BEGIN { RS = "S:S6...|\n" }

# Start of the string
RT != "\n" { 
  sub(".", ",")         # Replace first char by a comma
  pst = $0              # Remember the rest of the string
  pre = RT              # Remember the S:S6 pattern
}

# End of string
RT == "\n" { 
  gsub("[A-Z.]+", ",")  # Replace letters and dots by commas
  print pre pst $0      # Print the final result
}
```

Run e.g. it like this:

```
s=807001S:S6S11ABB23668732CC1DD1496851208.807262EE7482
gawk -f parse.awk <<<$s
```

Output:

```
S:S6S11,07001,23668732,1,1496851208,807262,7482
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could do it with `sed`:

*parse.sed*

```sed
h                         # Duplicate string to hold space
s/.*(S:S6...).*/\1/       # Extract the desired pattern
x                         # Swap hold and pattern space
s/S:S6...//               # Remove pattern (still in hold space)
s/[A-Z.]+/,/g             # Replace letters and dots with commas
s/./,/                    # Replace first char with comma
G                         # Append hold space content
s/([^\n]+)\n(.*)/\2\1/    # Rearrange to match desired output
```

Run it like this:

```
s=807001S:S6S11ABB23668732CC1DD1496851208.807262EE7482
sed -Ef parse.sed <<<$s
```

Output:

```
S:S6S11,07001,23668732,1,1496851208,807262,7482
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like this MAY be what you're really trying to do:

```
$ awk -F'[A-Z]{2,}|[.]' -v OFS=',' '{$1=substr($1,7) OFS substr($1,2,5)}1' file
S:S6S11,07001,23668732,1,1496851208,807262,7482
```

but your requirements for how and what to match where are very unclear and just one sample input line doesn't help much.